# How to extract json using express router?

Tags: express, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a JSON object to my server using post:

```
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var params = {
     firstname: "Joe",
     lastname: "Bloggs"
 };
 xhr.open('post', '/api/endpoint');
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.responseType = 'json';
 xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
     ...
 });
 xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

I am using express to handle requests:

```
...
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
...
```

then at my api endpoint I am using Express Router:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
router.post('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

When I print out req.body I get the following:

```
{ '{"firstname":"Joe","lastname":"Bloggs"}': '' }
```

If I use JSON.parse(req.body) I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
>       at JSON.parse ()

How can I get the contents of the payload in a format that I can work with, i.e. a json object?

Comment: Use a Content-type of "application/json" instead of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in the request header you send. If you also use bodyparser.json as a middleware req.body will be valid json.  You will not have to convert it by JSON.parse.

Comment: Can you only have one type of bodyparser, or will express be able detect it based on the content-type?

Comment: I use more than one body parser in my projects. I'm not sure but I think the middleware filters the content by the content-type defined in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicate that you will be sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` here:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

and here you send JSON:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

which is a clear violation. Make sure that you respect the format you indicated to the server when making your request:

```
var payload = 'firstname=' + encodeURIComponent(params.firstname) + 
              '&lastname=' + encodeURIComponent(params.lastname);
xhr.send(payload);
```

If on the other hand you would like to send JSON content then you could add the corresponding body parser on the server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
```

then set the proper Content-Type request header on the client:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

and now you can `JSON.stringify` when sending the request:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

at the api endpoint, the JSON can then be extracted from `req.body` (no need to use `JSON.parse`)